# My nodejs script can not send long messages

Tags: node.js, websocket, limit, packet

I have opened a WebSocket server in Nodejs with

```
var wsServer = new webSocketServer({
    // WebSocket server is tied to a HTTP server. WebSocket request is just
    // an enhanced HTTP request
    httpServer: server,
    //autoAcceptConnections: false
});
```

And then it's fine to communicate with the client side (browser js script) transferring small (1-2k bytes) packages. Also, it's fine to receive 1Mb packets on the client side.

But when I try to send 71k packet from the client side, connection is closed immediately without onerror event and any error messages. I don't understand what happen there. Do you know?

Packets 56kbytes sending fine from the client side, so I guess "error" packet size is 64kbytes. There is a limitation somewhere, I think.

Here is the code used to create a client at the browser side

```
var wsconn = new WebSocket('wss://mydomain:11122');
```

What I did wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution by myself. It turned out that the maximum allowable frame size for sending to the server is not set by the browser, but by the server itself. In my case, I needed to increase this value (which is 65536 by default) using the following code:

```
var wsServer = new webSocketServer({
    httpServer: server,
    maxReceivedFrameSize: 2048000,    // Added this line
    maxReceivedMessageSize: 2048000,    // And this line
});
```

Thus, maximum frame size for my server become around 2Mbytes which is pretty enough for my application.